# Regex: optimal syntax for optional combined expression?

Tags: regex

I want to match a combination of expressions that is optional. In this specific example, I want to match on the word **through**. Also, if the words **run** or **swim** precede through (with whitespace) then match on the whole phrase. So that combination of expressions preceding **through** must be optional.

I want all the following lines to be positive matches:

```
swim through <-- match entire phrase
jump through <-- match entire phrase
hike through <-- match only the word "through"
```

To do this, I can use the following expression:

```
(jump\W|swim\W)?through
```

However, is it possible to accomplish the same thing without having to add `\W` after `jump` and `swim`? I was trying something like this:

```
(jump|swim)?\W?through
```

But that wasn't working properly because it would include the space that precedes *through* on the 3rd example. I only want the word *through*, not the whitespace around it.

Comment: I really don't think it matters. It'll still produce a very similar FSA

Comment: When you say "match", do you also mean "extract"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this one: `(?:(jump|swim)\W)?through`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. What exactly does the `?:` do?

Comment: It indicates non-capturing group.